# Select only table that don't meet specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 table and i tried to get table 1 which contains Job_ID which has not finish the progress in table 2.
Table 1. [Job]

### Job_ID (key)    |GroupID

```
1410        |    A  
2309        |    B  
3456        |    C
```

Table 2. [Progress]

### Job_ID          |Percent

```
1410        |    10
1410        |    50
1410        |    60
2309        |    50
2309        |    100
3456        |    100
```

Expected:

### Job_ID (key)    |GroupID

```
1410        |    A
```

My SQL Query is:

`SELECT FROM Job,(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Progress 
WHERE Percent<100) AS PGR
WHERE Job.Job_ID = PGR.Job_ID`

But i still get this

### Job_ID (key)    |GroupID

```
1410        |    A  
2309        |    B
```

My logic was getting only Job_ID which has Percent < 100 but i failed to find specific way in SQL in stackoverflow. Please help me in this case.

Comment: Don't have what? Please at least edit the title.

Comment: @Sami I fixed the title sorry i am new to stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can take help from below Query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 b WHERE a.job_id = b.job_id and percentage = 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

use not exists

```
select
    a.* from job a   
   where not exists (select 1 from progres b 
                      where a.job_id =b.job_id and b.Percent=100
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and `NULL` check?

```
SELECT T1.JobID, T2.GroupID
FROM Table1 T1
     LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.JobID = T2.JobId
                 AND T2.Percent = 100
WHERE T2.JobID IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this, i am new to sql so left right join makes me confused a bit :(

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 select
    job.*
    from
    job

    where 
not exists (select 1 from progres where progres.job_id =job.job_id)
```

Comment: What about `percent`?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Which percent you want? cause you have more than 1 in some cases.